# haproxy stats: qtime,ctime,rtime,ttime?

Tags: haproxy, metrics, latency

Running a web app behind HAProxy 1.6.3-1ubuntu0.1, I'm getting haproxy stats `qtime,ctime,rtime,ttime` values of `0,0,0,2704`.

From the docs (https://www.haproxy.org/download/1.6/doc/management.txt):

```
 58. qtime [..BS]: the average queue time in ms over the 1024 last requests
 59. ctime [..BS]: the average connect time in ms over the 1024 last requests
 60. rtime [..BS]: the average response time in ms over the 1024 last requests
     (0 for TCP)
 61. ttime [..BS]: the average total session time in ms over the 1024 last requests
```

I'm expecting response times in the 0-10ms range. `ttime` of 2704 milliseconds seems unrealistically high. Is it possible the units are off and this is 2704 microseconds rather than 2704 millseconds?

Secondly, it seems suspicious that `ttime` isn't even close to `qtime+ctime+rtime`. Is total response time not the sum of the time to queue, connect, and respond? What is the other time, that is included in total but not queue/connect/response? Why can my response times be <1ms, but my total response times be ~2704 ms?

Here is my full csv stats:

```
$ curl "http://localhost:9000/haproxy_stats;csv"
# pxname,svname,qcur,qmax,scur,smax,slim,stot,bin,bout,dreq,dresp,ereq,econ,eresp,wretr,wredis,status,weight,act,bck,chkfail,chkdown,lastchg,downtime,qlimit,pid,iid,sid,throttle,lbtot,tracked,type,rate,rate_lim,rate_max,check_status,check_code,check_duration,hrsp_1xx,hrsp_2xx,hrsp_3xx,hrsp_4xx,hrsp_5xx,hrsp_other,hanafail,req_rate,req_rate_max,req_tot,cli_abrt,srv_abrt,comp_in,comp_out,comp_byp,comp_rsp,lastsess,last_chk,last_agt,qtime,ctime,rtime,ttime,
http-in,FRONTEND,,,4707,18646,50000,5284057,209236612829,42137321877,0,0,997514,,,,,OPEN,,,,,,,,,1,2,0,,,,0,4,0,2068,,,,0,578425742,0,997712,22764,1858,,1561,3922,579448076,,,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,
servers,server1,0,0,0,4337,20000,578546476,209231794363,41950395095,,0,,22861,1754,95914,0,no check,1,1,0,,,,,,1,3,1,,578450562,,2,1561,,6773,,,,0,578425742,0,198,0,0,0,,,,29,1751,,,,,0,,,0,0,0,2704,
servers,BACKEND,0,0,0,5919,5000,578450562,209231794363,41950395095,0,0,,22861,1754,95914,0,UP,1,1,0,,0,320458,0,,1,3,0,,578450562,,1,1561,,3922,,,,0,578425742,0,198,22764,1858,,,,,29,1751,0,0,0,0,0,,,0,0,0,2704,
stats,FRONTEND,,,2,5,2000,5588,639269,8045341,0,0,29,,,,,OPEN,,,,,,,,,1,4,0,,,,0,1,0,5,,,,0,5374,0,29,196,0,,1,5,5600,,,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,
stats,BACKEND,0,0,0,1,200,196,639269,8045341,0,0,,196,0,0,0,UP,0,0,0,,0,320458,0,,1,4,0,,0,,1,0,,5,,,,0,0,0,0,196,0,,,,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,0,0,0,0,
```

Comment: you ever figure out the cause of this I'm facing a similar situation where the other times barely add up to the total time? If total time is only about first byte, and not about content response time I'm not sure what's taking it so long.

Comment: I researched this, and I found an reference to the following forum:
https://discourse.haproxy.org/t/total-time-stat-seems-high-on-stats-page/3129/2

It seems like ttime includes http keep-alive connections which are longer lived.  The timing is the average _session_ time for the last 1024 requests.

Answer (score 2):

In haproxy >2 you now get two values `n / n` which is the max within a sliding window and the average for that window. The max value remains the max across all sample windows until a higher value is found. On 1.8 you only get the average.

Example of haproxy 2 v 1.8. Note these proxies are used very differently and with dramatically different loads.

[image: haproxy 2.2.8]

[image: haproxy 1.8]

So looks like the average response times at least since last reboot are 66m and 275ms.

The average is computed as:

```
data time + cumulative http connections - 1 / cumulative http connections
```

This might not be a perfect analysis so if anyone has improvements it'd be appreciated. This is meant to show how I came to the answer above so you can use it to gather more insight into the other counters you asked about. Most of this information was gathered from reading [stats.c](https://github.com/haproxy/haproxy/blob/040b1195f70d6a24204ede081451fd1dd71e6a34/src/stats.c#L219). The counters you asked about are defined [here](https://github.com/haproxy/haproxy/blob/040b1195f70d6a24204ede081451fd1dd71e6a34/include/haproxy/counters-t.h).

````cpp
unsigned int q_time, c_time, d_time, t_time; /* sums of conn_time, queue_time, data_time, total_time */
unsigned int qtime_max, ctime_max, dtime_max, ttime_max; /* maximum of conn_time, queue_time, data_time, total_time observed */```
````

The stats page values are built from this code:

```cpp
if (strcmp(field_str(stats, ST_F_MODE), "http") == 0)
            chunk_appendf(out, "<tr><th>- Responses time:</th><td>%s / %s</td><td>ms</td></tr>",
                      U2H(stats[ST_F_RT_MAX].u.u32), U2H(stats[ST_F_RTIME].u.u32));
            chunk_appendf(out, "<tr><th>- Total time:</th><td>%s / %s</td><td>ms</td></tr>",
                  U2H(stats[ST_F_TT_MAX].u.u32), U2H(stats[ST_F_TTIME].u.u32));
```

You asked about all the counter but I'll focus on one. As can be seen in the snippit above for "Response time:" `ST_F_RT_MAX` and `ST_F_RTIME` are the values displayed on the stats page as `n (rtime_max) / n (rtime)` respectively. These are defined as follows:

```cpp
[ST_F_RT_MAX] = { .name = "rtime_max", .desc = "Maximum observed time spent waiting for a server response, in milliseconds (backend/server)" },
[ST_F_RTIME] = { .name = "rtime", .desc = "Time spent waiting for a server response, in milliseconds, averaged over the 1024 last requests (backend/server)" },
```

These set a "metric" value (among other things) in a case statement further down in the code:

```cpp
case ST_F_RT_MAX:
    metric = mkf_u32(FN_MAX, sv->counters.dtime_max);
    break;
case ST_F_RTIME:
    metric = mkf_u32(FN_AVG, swrate_avg(sv->counters.d_time, srv_samples_window));
    break;
```

These metric values give us a good look at what the stats page is telling us. The first value in the "Responses time: **0** / 0" `ST_F_RT_MAX`, is some **max value** time spent waiting. The second value in "Responses time: 0 / **0**" `ST_F_RTIME` is an **average** time taken for each connection. These are the max and average taken within a window of time, i.e. however long it takes for you to get 1024 connections.

For example "Responses time: 10000 / 20":

- max time spent waiting (max value ever reached including http keepalive time) over the last 1024 connections 10 seconds
- average time over the last 1024 connections 20ms

So for all intents and purposes

```cpp
rtime_max = dtime_max
rtime = swrate_avg(d_time, srv_samples_window)
```

Which begs the question what is `dtime_max` `d_time` and `srv_sample_window`? These are the data time windows, I couldn't actually figure how these time values are being set, but at face value it's "some time" for the last 1024 connections. As pointed out [here](https://discourse.haproxy.org/t/total-time-stat-seems-high-on-stats-page/3129/3) keepalive times are included in max totals which is why the numbers are high.

Now that we know `ST_F_RT_MAX` is a max value and `ST_F_RTIME` is an average, an average of what?

```cpp
/* compue time values for later use */
if (selected_field == NULL || *selected_field == ST_F_QTIME ||
    *selected_field == ST_F_CTIME || *selected_field == ST_F_RTIME ||
    *selected_field == ST_F_TTIME) {
    srv_samples_counter = (px->mode == PR_MODE_HTTP) ? sv->counters.p.http.cum_req : sv->counters.cum_lbconn;
    if (srv_samples_counter < TIME_STATS_SAMPLES && srv_samples_counter > 0)
        srv_samples_window = srv_samples_counter;
}
```

`TIME_STATS_SAMPLES` value is defined as

```cpp
#define TIME_STATS_SAMPLES 512
unsigned int srv_samples_window = TIME_STATS_SAMPLES;
```

In mode http `srv_sample_counter` is `sv->counters.p.http.cum_req`. `http.cum_req` is defined as `ST_F_REQ_TOT`.

```cpp
[ST_F_REQ_TOT]  = { .name = "req_tot",  .desc = "Total number of HTTP requests processed by this object since the worker process started" },
```

For example if the value of `http.cum_req` is 10, then `srv_sample_counter` will be 10. The sample appears to be the number of successful requests for a given sample window for a given backends server. `d_time` (data time) is passed as "sum" and is computed as some non-negative value or it's counted as an error. I thought I found the code for how `d_time` is created but I wasn't sure so I haven't included it.

```
/* Returns the average sample value for the sum <sum> over a sliding window of
 * <n> samples. Better if <n> is a power of two. It must be the same <n> as the
 * one used above in all additions.
 */
static inline unsigned int swrate_avg(unsigned int sum, unsigned int n)
{
    return (sum + n - 1) / n;
}
```